# lead / lag Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have a field (track change)
that only gives me a value for the first line but wants to pass this on to the next one ...

with lead / lag function - that does not work
[image]

Comment: What is the source of the `26` values in the `should be` column?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the source of `26` value in the `should be` column is `BC003`, `Lead` can be used as shown below:

```
With tab (BC003) as( Select 1 from dual
               UNION ALL
             Select 18 from dual
             UNION ALL
             Select 26 from dual)
Select BC003, NVL(Lead(BC003) over (Order by 1),BC003) "Shoud be"
from tab;
```

Output:

```
SQL> /

     BC003   Shoud be
---------- ----------
         1         18
        18         26
        26         26
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data( id, object, bc003, track_change ) AS
SELECT 121, 12,  1, 15   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 121, 13,  1, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 121, 14,  1, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 121, 15,  1, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 121, 16,  1, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 121, 12, 18, 22   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 121, 13, 18, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 121, 14, 18, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 121, 15, 18, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 121, 16, 18, NULL FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

You can use an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       MIN( track_change ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id, bc003 ) AS track_change_new
FROM   test_data t
```

**Query 2**:

You can use `LAG` with the `IGNORE NULLS` clause:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       COALESCE(
         track_change,
         LAG( track_change ) IGNORE NULLS OVER (
           PARTITION BY id, bc003
           ORDER BY object
         )
       ) AS track_change_new
FROM   test_data t
```

**Output**:

Both output the same:

> ```
>  ID | OBJECT | BC003 | TRACK_CHANGE | TRACK_CHANGE_NEW
> --: | -----: | ----: | -----------: | ---------------:
> 121 |     12 |     1 |           15 |               15
> 121 |     13 |     1 |         null |               15
> 121 |     14 |     1 |         null |               15
> 121 |     15 |     1 |         null |               15
> 121 |     16 |     1 |         null |               15
> 121 |     12 |    18 |           22 |               22
> 121 |     13 |    18 |         null |               22
> 121 |     14 |    18 |         null |               22
> 121 |     15 |    18 |         null |               22
> 121 |     16 |    18 |         null |               22
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9b71dd9acc34ea98dab2801e14a760a1)*